# Disable input fields based on timestamp of mysql timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm programming a betting game for football tournaments/cups. In this game users shall be able to place their bets in a form until 5 minutes before the match starts. After that point in time the fields shall be disabled/greyed out so that it still shows the entered value but is not editable anyore.

How can I disable these "score input fields" automatically based on the `time` and `date` (saved for each game in the mysql table)?

If you need to see more of the code or need more info about the mysql tables, please ask.

**SQL Query & table**

```
$records = mysqli_query($conn, "
    SELECT
        sp.spiel_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(sp.datum, \"%d.%m.%Y\") AS datum, 
        DATE_FORMAT(sp.zeit, \"%H:%i\") AS zeit, 
        sp.heimteam_id,
        sp.gastteam_id,
        sp.tore_heimteam,
        sp.tore_gastteam,
        ht.teamname AS heimteam_name,
        at.teamname AS gastteam_name,
        t.match_id,
        t.user_id,
        t.tipp_heim,
        t.tipp_gast,
        t.punkte_tipp,
        u.user_id,
        u.username
    FROM 
        spielplan sp
    LEFT JOIN mannschaften ht
        ON sp.heimteam_id = ht.mannschafts_id
    LEFT JOIN mannschaften at
        ON sp.gastteam_id = at.mannschafts_id
    LEFT JOIN tipps t
        ON sp.spiel_id = t.match_id
    LEFT JOIN users u
        ON t.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE 
        username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'
    ORDER BY 
        spiel_id ASC
");
while($fields = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="spiel_ids[]" value="<?php echo $fields["spiel_id"] ?>">
        <td><?php echo $fields["datum"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["zeit"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["heimteam_name"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["tore_heimteam"] ?></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["tore_gastteam"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["gastteam_name"] ?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_ids[]" value="<?php echo $fields["user_id"] ?>">
        <td><input type="tel" maxlength="2" size="5" name="tipps_heim[]" value="<?php echo $fields["tipp_heim"] ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="tel" maxlength="2" size="5" name="tipps_gast[]" value="<?php echo $fields["tipp_gast"] ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $fields["punkte_tipp"] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sql, js and php in one file...man

Comment: Nothing as I have no idea on how to achieve that. My only thought is to use javascript to add `readonly` to the input field at the "match-time" minus 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend you doing this, but you can try this:

For example it's your field that you want to disable

```
<input name="spiel_ids[]" value="<?php echo $fields["spiel_id"] ?>">
```

You can declare $disabled variable based on you db record:

```
    <?php 
    $disabled = "";

    //you check if you date is in future, then you disable field
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fields['datum'])) > date('Y-m-d')) { 

      $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
    } ?>
```

And put this variable to your output string:

```
<input <?php echo $disabled ?> name="spiel_ids[]" value="<?php echo $fields["spiel_id"] ?>">
```

Comment: Why would you not recomment this? Seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind it's too easy to cheat with. One line of code enables the input again, so you would still have to add code to check if bets are still allowed in the bet handling script. It would probably be safer to just remove the input and replace it by a text field.

Comment: I would not reccomend using sql and php in one file.